# Minimum Normalizer

Tags: calculus

Let $x_1\ge x_2\ge\dots \ge x_n> 0$. What is the minimum value of $k$ such that $$\frac{nkx_i}{x_1+\dots+x_n}\ge 1\quad \forall i.$$

I tried a bit hoping that $k=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$  would work. But not getting any clue. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the minimum $k>0$ such that
$$
k\, x_i\geq \overline{x}, \quad \forall i = 1, \ldots, n,
\qquad
\text{where}\ \overline{x} := \frac{x_1 + \cdots + x_n}{n}\,.
$$
Since, by assumption, $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \cdots \geq x_n > 0$, the above $n$ inequalities are satisfied if and only if $k\, x_n \geq \overline{x}$. Hence, the minimum of such values of $k$ is $k = \overline{x} / x_n$.

Comment: Sure, you are right, for some reason I was considering the reversed inequality!

Comment: Thanks. That's right. However, is it possible to obtain the bound in terms of $k=1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}$ possibly with some multiplicative (constant) factor?